# .NET Core (3.0) MVC - How to redirect to a different view / .cshtml page?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

1. I have a view called WxJS.cshtml. I uses JavaScript to get JSON data. That JSON data is sent to a Wx controller
2. The Wx controller manipulates the JSON data and using Twilio I'm getting a text message - which clearly indicates that the code is working in this controller.

The ask / question I have please is how do I get the Wx controller to redirect from the WxJS.cshtml Razor view to the Wx.cshtml Razor view to present that data?

I've set a breakpoint on the Wx.chstml page - program control drops into that breakpoint - from what I can tell it is the last breakpoint to be hit. That said, the Wx.chstml page does not load the browser continues to display the WxJS.cshtml page.

I'm missing something (probably obvious) as I've been working on finding a solution for this for hours :-(

Thank you in advance!! :-)
**WxJS Razor View**

```
    <!doctype html>
<title>Example</title>

<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.511virginia.org/data/geojson/icons.rwis.geojson";


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            showWeather(jsonData);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

    function showWeather(data) {
        var output = "<ul>";
        var i;
        for (var i in data.features) {
           output += "<li>" + data.features[i].id  + "</li>";
        }
        output += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("wxList").innerHTML = output;



        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Wx/',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').html("Success!");
            }
        });




    }</script>


<div id="wxList"></div>

** Home WX Controller **

     [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Wx([FromBody] RootObject data)
        {


            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

            List<ConcerningWeatherData> WxStatDataList = new List<ConcerningWeatherData>();



            RootObjectItteration ObjItteratrion = new RootObjectItteration();
            WxStatDataList = ObjItteratrion.ItterateThroughRootObjectSettingValues(data, WxStatDataList);
            List<ConcerningWeatherData> SortedList = new List<ConcerningWeatherData>();
            try
            {
                SortedList = WxStatDataList.OrderBy(o => o.indexId).ToList();
                ViewBag.WxStatDataList = SortedList;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { ex.ToString(); }




            try
            {
                TwilioSendText SendText = new TwilioSendText();
                string sendToUser = SendText.ParseThroughWhatWxToSendUser(SortedList);

                TwilioSendText numbers = new TwilioSendText();
                List<String> listOfPhoneNumbers = new List<String>();
                listOfPhoneNumbers = numbers.listOfPhoneNumbersToSendTo(listOfPhoneNumbers);

                // TURN TWILIO SEND TEXT ON OR OFF HERE:
                SendText.sendTextMessages(sendToUser, listOfPhoneNumbers);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { ex.ToString(); }


            //return View();
            return View("Wx", "Home");


            //return View();
            // return Redirect("https://localhost:5001/Home/Wx.cshtml");



        }
```

**And the view I'm trying to get the controller to direct to Wx.cshtml**
(I have an identical page Weather.cshtml and when I use .NET Core to populate the JSON it displays this Weather.cshtml page) Again, Twilio is sending me a text with all data so I know the JSON parsing is working.

```
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "C-Ville West";@*Privacy Policywas Privacy.cshtml*@
}
@*<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>*@

<p></p>
@* loop over viewbag object *@
@foreach (var x in ViewBag.WxStatDataList)

{
    // wx station name & description
    <b>@x.description @x.name</b> @Html.Raw("<font color=#A9A9A9>(") @x.id @Html.Raw(")</font><br />")


    // check station for bad / dangerous weather
     @*x.weather_station_has_potentially_dangerous_weather @Html.Raw("<br />")*@
    @if (@x.weather_station_has_potentially_dangerous_weather == true)
    {
        // then output any potentially dangerous weather
     @Html.Raw("<font color=#ff0000>")@x.weather_stations_potentially_dangerous_conditions @Html.Raw("</font><br />");
    }

    // visibility
    if (x.dont_show_visibility == false)
    {
        if (@x.visibility_show_value == true && @x.visibility_at_onePointTwoMiles_message_showTF == false)
        {
        @x.visibility  @Html.Raw(" visibility<br />")
        }
        else if (@x.visibility_at_onePointTwoMiles_message_showTF = true)
        {
        @x.visibility_at_onePointTwoMiles_message @Html.Raw(" visibility<br />")
        }
        else
        {
        @x.visibility_inoperative.ToString() @Html.Raw("<br />")
        }
    }
    else
    {
         @x.visibility_inoperative.ToString() @Html.Raw("<br />")
    }

    // air temp
    if (x.dont_show_air_temperature ==false)
    {
        if (@x.air_temperature_show_value == true)
        {
        @x.air_temperature @Html.Raw("&#176; air temperature<br />")
        }
        else
        {
        @x.air_temperature_inoperative.ToString() @Html.Raw("<br />")
        }
    }

    // surface temp
    if (@x.dont_show_surface_temperature == false)
    {
        if (@x.surface_temperature_show_value == true)
        {
        @x.surface_temperature  @Html.Raw("&#176; surface temperature<br />")
        }
        else
        {
        @x.surface_temperature_inoperative.ToString() @Html.Raw("<br />")
        }

    }
    // surface conditions
    if (@x.dont_show_surface_condition == false)
    {
    @x.surface_condition @Html.Raw("<br />")
    }

    // dewpoint
    if (@x.dewwpoint_temperature_show_value == true)
    {
        @x.dewpoint_temperature  @Html.Raw("&#176; dewpoint temperature<br />")
    }
    else
    {
        @x.dewpoint_temperature_inoperative @Html.Raw("<br />")
    }

    // relative humidity
    if (@x.relative_humidity_show_value == true)
    {
        @x.relative_humidity @Html.Raw("&#8453: relative humidity<br />")
    }
    else
    {
        @x.relative_humidity_inoperative @Html.Raw("<br />")
    }

    // wind direction -- speed -- gusts to
    if (@x.dont_show_wind == false)
    {
        @x.all_wind_data @Html.Raw("<br />")
    }




}

@*measurements in disclaimer*@
Temperatures in Fahrenheit, windpeeds in MPH. @Html.Raw("<br />")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That said, the Wx.chstml page does not load the browser continues to display the WxJS.cshtml page.

That is because you used ajax.Ajax allow you display the return data in the current view.

- If you want to render Wx.cshtml,you could append the return html to
  your current WxJs.cshtml:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Wx()
{

    ViewBag.WxStatDataList = SortedList;
    return View();
}
```

Ajax:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Wx/',
            type: 'POST',
            //...
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#test").html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

- If you actually want to redirect to the the Wx.cshtml,you need to use
  session to store the data due to the lifetime of ViewBag:

1.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void TestWx()
{
     //...
     var SortedList = WxStatDataList.OrderBy(o => o.indexId).ToList();
     HttpContext.Session.SetObject("ComplexObject", SortedList);
     //no need to return View()...
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Wx()
{
    ViewBag.WxStatDataList= HttpContext.Session.GetObject<List<ConcerningWeatherData>>("ComplexObject");
    return View();
}
```

2.Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/TestWx/',  //change this
            type: 'POST',
            //..
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = "/Home/Wx"; //redirect to Wx.cshtml
            }
        });
});    
</script>
```

3.SessionExtensions:

```
using System.Text.Json;
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
}
```

4.Register session in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSession();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{        
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseSession();
    //...

}
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you. This is helpful on so many levels - really gave me an understanding as to what is going on. Thank you again, this has to be one of the best answers - each option having a clear example is incredible. Thank you again!!!!